# How to get f.select for static hash value rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have static hash :

```
STATUS_BRAND = {
    active: "hoatdong",
    deactive: "khonghoatdong",
  }.freeze
```

my view:

```
= f.select :status, Brand::STATUS_BRAND, class: "form-control post-type input-bg"
```

i wanto display value in here is : "hoatdong" and "khonghotdong" in views

Comment: To get the array of values: `Brand::STATUS_BRAND.values`

Comment: It still does not receive the value sent
 It does not understand
value i wanto sent is `active` and `deactive` @maxpleaner

Comment: if you `Brand::STATUS_BRAND.key` then it okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the select to return the keys to Rails, then you have to invert the Hash:

```
f.select(:status, options_for_select(Brand::STATUS_BRAND.invert), ...)
```

Output:

```
<option value="active">hoatdong</option>
<option value="deactive">khonghoatdong</option>
```

You can [look at the documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) for `options_for_select` for more examples.